# dll connection c# MODELS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dll

hope someone can help me, I made a DLL with a connection string to sql server, I added it to my references into my web project (C# .net mvc),

this is how I pass the information to my reference dll connection (from web.config):

```
<add key="dataSource" value="Server = ****; Database = ****; User ID = ****; PWD = *****;" />
```

So when I try to make my Data Models, I don´t now how to make it without creating a new connection to my database.

thanks

Comment: `= ConfigurationManager.ConnectionString("dataSource");`

Comment: sorry, im a little lost, If want to make a Models, click in models -> add new element, ADO.NET Entity Data Model, how i add my dll there without a new connection?

Comment: assuming, you are using mvc 4, you dont need to add new model just pick existing connection string from model builder window vs -> new item-> ado.net entity data model-> ef designer from db-> choose data connection (choose from web config) -> next steps & done 
important : remember to first connect with db in server explorer, so it can be picked up